# Trace Debugging - Übersetzung von trace?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

In letzter Zeit begegnen mir immer wieder Worte wie "trace debugging" oder "power trace" im Englischen, für die mir keine sinnvollen Übersetzungen einfallen.

Ein "trace" beschreibt dabei eine Art Zeitstrahl, über den das Verhalten des Systems abgelesen werden kann.

Quelle:
http://www.iar.com/en/IAR/Webinars/How-to-Spot-the-Bottlenecks-in-Your-Application-Trace-Debugging-on-ARM-Cortex-M3/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wie ich schon in der Vergangenheit angedeutet habe, scheint mir im IT-Umfeld eine Übersetzung von Fachbegriffen unüblich zu sein; das heißt dann auch in der Folge, dass jeder Versuch, eine Übersetzung zu finden, bei Menschen, die den Begriff schon kennen, Irritation auslöst und dass man häufig besser gar nicht übersetzt.

Das gilt auch in diesem Fall: Wenn mir jemand erzählt, dass er mir den Trace eines Programmauflaufs zukommen lässt, dann weiß ich, was er meint. Würde er von einer "Spur" oder Ähnlichem sprechen, müsste ich nachfragen.

Ob dieser Zustand jetzt schlimm ist oder nicht, das ist wohl Geschmackssache. Ich stehe da auf dem Standpunkt, dass ein etablierter englischer Fachbegriff durch seine Abgrenzung vom Deutschen eine klarere Kommunikation ermöglicht. Dann kann man auch sagen, dass man durch einen Trace einem komplexen Bug auf die Spur gekommen ist.

Comment: Warum eigentlich _der_ Trace?

Comment: @kontur: Warum ich da "der" gesagt habe (und mir auch nichts anderes vorstellen kann) weiß ich nicht. Ich würde auch *der Speicherdump* sagen (obwohl das deutsche Pendant "Abbild" ja ein Neutrum ist). Vielleicht kann jemand mit mehr Ahnung von deutscher Grammatik ja weiterhelfen.

Answer (score 3):

Hier gilt doch vermutlich die Faustregel, dass das einfachste Ergebnis sehr wahrscheinlich auch zutrifft. Die gängige Übersetzung eines "trace" ist eine Spur, die von etwas hinterlassen wurde.

Und der Zeitstrahl, den du da erwähnst, ist doch auch eher die Spur, die die Prozesse des Systems hinterlassen und die nachverfolgt werden oder bin ich da ganz auf dem Holzweg?

Also "trace debugging" als eine Art wirkungsorientierte Fehlersuche im Sinne des Beobachtens der Effekte, die das Programm während seines Ablaufs so hervorruft (seiner Spur).

"power trace" ist mir da gerade der Zusammenhang entgangen, klingt ohne Kontext aber sehr nach einer Energieverbrauchs-Kurve.

Comment: Wie 0x6d64 schon geschrieben hat klingt für mich Spur wie von einem anderen Stern, sodass ich den Begriff in meiner Arbeit einfach definieren werde und dann als solchen verwende.

Answer (score 2):

Anders als im richtigen Leben kann *"trace"* im Kontext einer Programmfehlersuche nicht ohne Weiteres mit *"Spur"* übersetzt werden, ohne dass dadurch die Verständlichkeit der Fachsprache leidet.

Wenn man den Begriff unbedingt übersetzen muss, bieten sich folgende Varianten an (nachzulesen in den jeweilig verlinkten Dokumenten):

> - **Steuerung des Programmablaufs**, insbesondere durch Haltepunkte und die Einzelschritt-Verarbeitung von Befehlen <sup>[Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger)</sup>
> - Die gängigste Debugging-Technik ist die **Überwachung des Programmablaufs**. Anwendungsprogramme machen das, indem an den passenden Stellen printf eingefügt wird. <sup>[Oreilly: Debugging Techniken](http://www.oreilly.de/german/freebooks/linuxdrive2ger/debug.html)</sup>

Einfacher ist es, den Fachterminus *"Trace-Debugging"* unübersetzt zu lassen, da er von jemand, der sich mit Debugging auseinandersetzt, ganz sicher verstanden werden wird.

Answer (score 0):

Fehlersuche durch Spurenanalyse, Fehlererkennung durch Spurenanalyse, Fehlerverarbeitung durch Spurenanalyse, Fehlerkorrektur durch Spurenanalyse

Je nachdem, was Debugging im Kontext genau bedeutet.

Answer (score 0):

**Statusprotokoll** wäre eine mögliche Übersetzung für ein "trace log", "trace debugging" demnach

- **Fehlersuche mit Hilfe eines Statusprotokolls** oder
- **Fehlersuche anhand von Statusprotokolleinträgen**.

Ein *Protokoll* ist eine chronologische Abfolge wie sie in einem Programmablauf typisch ist. *Status* wiederum von der wörtlichen Übersetzung von "trace" - Durchschlagkopie, also ein Spiegelbild oder eine Momentaufnahme, ein Status.

Wie in anderen Antworten vorgeschlagen würde ich persönlich allerdings auch den nicht übersetzten Begriff vorziehen.